# Check contents of uploaded Excel spreadsheet into SQL Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, visual-studio

I am new to ASP.NET and C#. I am using VS2005 C# and SQL Server 2005.

I have two import functions in my web application which imports data from Excel spreadsheet into the SQL Server database.

The import functions work fine. However, there are situations where the server can be brought down due to improper checking of the data inside the Excel spreadsheet uploaded.

Below is my code snippet for the import function:

**.XLS and .XLSX**

---

```
if (FileImport.HasFile)
        {

            // Get the name of the Excel spreadsheet to upload. 
            string strFileName = Server.HtmlEncode(FileImport.FileName);

            // Get the extension of the Excel spreadsheet. 
            string strExtension = Path.GetExtension(strFileName);

            // Validate the file extension. 
            if (strExtension == ".xls" || strExtension == ".xlsx")
            {
                    // Generate the file name to save. 
                    string strUploadFileName = "C:/Documents and Settings/user01/My Documents/Visual Studio 2005/WebSites/MajorProject/UploadFiles/" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + strExtension;

                    // Save the Excel spreadsheet on server. 
                    FileImport.SaveAs(strUploadFileName);

                    // Create Connection to Excel Workbook
                    string connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + strUploadFileName + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";

                    using (OleDbConnection connection =
                                 new OleDbConnection(connStr))
                    {
                        string selectStmt = string.Format("Select [COLUMNS]  FROM [userlist$]");

                        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(selectStmt, connection);

                        connection.Open();
                        Console.WriteLine("Connection Opened");
                        // Create DbDataReader to Data Worksheet
                        using (DbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            // SQL Server Connection String
                            string sqlConnectionString = "Data Source=<datasource>";

                            // Bulk Copy to SQL Server
                            using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy =
                                       new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnectionString))
                            {
                                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "UserDB";
                                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dr);
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

---

**.CSV***

---

```
if (strExtension == ".csv")
{
        // Generate the file name to save. 
        string dir = @"C:\Documents and Settings\user01\My Documents\Visual Studio 2005\WebSites\MajorProject\UploadFiles\";
        string mycsv = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + strExtension;
        // Save the Excel spreadsheet on server. 
        BaanImport.SaveAs(dir + mycsv);

        // Create Connection to Excel Workbook
        string connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + dir + ";Extended Properties=Text;";
        using (OleDbConnection ExcelConnection = new OleDbConnection(connStr))
        {
            string selectStmt = string.Format("SELECT [COLUMNS] FROM " + mycsv);

            OleDbCommand ExcelCommand = new OleDbCommand(selectStmt, ExcelConnection);

            OleDbDataAdapter ExcelAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(ExcelCommand);

            ExcelConnection.Open();

            using (DbDataReader dr = ExcelCommand.ExecuteReader())
            {
                // SQL Server Connection String
                string sqlConnectionString = "Data Source=<datasource>";

                // Bulk Copy to SQL Server
                using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy =
                           new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnectionString))
                {
                    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "UserDB";
                    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dr);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
}
```

---

*Situation 1* : E.g. my `SELECT` statement is `Select [Username], [Description]  FROM [userlist$]`. If my excel spreadsheet looks like this, it will bring down the whole server:

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Us9V3.png

---

May I know if there is any way to prevent the user from uploading this kind of excel spreadsheet which contains more than 1 of the column name?

Thank you for any help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I think that that easiest approach to this is to copy the data from the excel spreadsheet into a temporary table in the database that does not have any constraints or checks using your existing code.

You can then execute a stored procedure to validate the data and, if valid, copy it into the production table.

If the data is not valid, you can Raiserror or return an error code from your stored procedure to let the uploader know the data cannot be accepted.

Alternatively, you could devise the stored procedure to only process the valid data and just ignore the duplicates.